# Recommended read/write practices for saving/loading control data

Tags: java, android, saving-data

I've read the android development documentation and some here and I'm still a bit stuck on the approach to take.  Right now I'm building a small Android app that really is just a small POS (Point Of Sale) application.

I want the user to be able to save prices for items (inventory) and to be able to later re-use those prices.  I don't want to have to make the user enter in the price of the items each time the app is used.

Right now I'm struggling between shared-resources and filesystem/file.

Questions: 
In this situation, what is the best route?  When the user creates a new order, what is the best way of getting the prices?

Is it recommended to have a class with these values also, rather than just reading from a file?

Do you have to have a 1 to 1 ratio of Activity/Class files?  Can you instantiate a Class without starting the activity?

Comment: SharedPreferences uses a file to store data. Use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this situation, what is the best route? When the user creates a new
>   order, what is the best way of getting the prices?

I recommend you to use CursorLoader and calls it on your onCreate method. Don't forget to release this resources before closing your activity.

> Do you have to have a 1 to 1 ratio of Activity/Class files?

No, you don't.

> Can you instantiate a Class without starting the activity?

Yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks Rodrgo!  I was just about to show my code that I have so far

Comment: I'll read up on:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: I think for the level of understanding and experience I have, I won't be able to implement this (CursorLoader) even though it is deemed as the answer.  Right now I will use a file save, file read.

Comment: I will implement a sample for you and publish on Github.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo Henriques